# Move working SVN working copy into new directory and tagging current checkin?

Tags: svn

This question comes to you from someone who's been burned by SVN before and am henceforward afraid of it. So I have a little problem because I was stupid when I was working on my SVN repo. I was developing a project, let's say containing one file, that I just released as a first minor version. So my svn repo looked like this:

```
project/
--> main.py (v1)
```

Notice, that I did *not* create the usual `trunk`, `branch`, and `tags` folders as I should've. Now, I need to, but the problem is that I have since edited the file! Is there a way I can go from this:

```
Hard drive:
project/
--> main.py (v2)

SVN repo:
project/
--> main.py (v1)
```

to this:

```
Hard drive and SVN repo:
project/
--> trunk/
    --> main.py (v2)
--> tags/
    --> v1/
        --> main.py (v1)
--> branch/
```

Thanks for any/all help!

PS Please note that "Switch to git!" is not an acceptable answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `svn` `move` and `copy` commands. They can work with URLs, which means that you can do changes on server-side.

You could copy or move main.py (v1) to tags/v1/ using URL->URL method.

```
svn move --parents http://svn/project/main.py http://svn/project/tags/v1/main.py
```

Then you can copy main.py (v2) to trunk/ using WC->URL method.

```
svn copy --parents main.py  http://svn/project/trunk/main.py
```

Since you don't have the directories trunk and tags, you may use `--parents` parameter, it will create the directories missing in the path.

See `svn help copy` and `svn help move` for more info about these commands

P.S. Just in case make a backup of your working copy.